# How to programmatically enable reviews and ratings in WooCommerce products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled Reviews from the Dashboard but they are not appearing in the front-end of my site. This could be an issue with the theme itself. Is there a function that displays the reviews and ratings section within my theme?

It's the `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/review.php` that needs to be displayed on the product pages but it's not showing at all.

Comment: If it shows while Twenty Fifteen is active, then you can verify the issue is with your theme. Josh has a great answer below that you should work through once you are sure it is your theme. Also, try contacting the theme author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few layers at work here. A few things you should check, in order of most likely to least likely culprit:

**Is another setting in the dashboard hiding the reviews tab?** There are other options below the "Enable reviews" checkbox. Review those, as they can hide the tab based on your front-end viewing user privileges.

**Is the review tab just getting hidden by CSS in your theme?** Go to the page's source code in Chrome Inspector (or whatever browser tool you're using) and CTRL+F "review" and cycle through any hits. If you find elements in the page body with "review" classes or ids, check to see if they're hidden, and if so, whether they're hiding the reviews tab.

**Is the reviews tab being hidden in the source code by a hook?** Search your entire project's source code (including plugins) for hooks that may be un-setting the reviews tabs. For example:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tab_panels', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_panel', 30);
```

**Are your theme's override templates removing reviews?** Check the /theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php file to see if it's markedly different from the base WooCommerce template, for instance not executing do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' )

**Did your WooCommerce base templates get altered?** Check for the same in the plugin files directly.

Comment: You were spot on. It was indeed hidden by a hook in functions.php. I put that there that myself over a year ago when I was customising the theme and totally forgot about it. Your checklist certainly helped me figure it out.

Comment: Excellent! I find that I am my own worst enemy 90% of the time with stuff like that. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 components to enable reviews on WooCommerce.

1. Enable comments in WordPress
2. Enable Reviews in WooCommerce
3. Enable reviews in the product

I will only discuss the third option which is not as documented on the web.

As of Woocommerce 3.7.0 (maybe even earlier), if a product was already created and then you enabled the review settings, then the product will have the reviews DISABLED. You must enable them on each product.

Manual:
Go to the Products->All Products menu on WordPress.
Click "Quick Edit" on a product. You will see a "Enable Reviews" checkbox just below the Product tag field. Check it.

Automated:
Got to phpMyAdmin and run a SQL command:
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open' WHERE post_type = 'product';

Comment: Best answer, especially the update command saved me few hours :)